# tsql select all or use a where condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am making an application which has a simple UI to show a database table. It allows user to enter a value to filter the rows or tick a checkbox to display the whole table.

Is it possible to make a where condition which return all rows
My target is to use a SQL "select blah, blah2, blah3 from tbl1 where blah = @anInputValue". But this SQL cannot return whole table for whatever value I passed.

| blah | blah2 | blah3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

When user check "select all", it returns 3 rows. When user enter 4, it returns the middle row

My problem is I have 4 "Select all" checkboxes, I do not want to make many queries and many "if then else" to select the right query.

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output with few inputs

Comment: Build the query in your app depending on UI.

Answer (score 4):

Like this you can leave the input parameter empty to get all values.

```
select *
from tbl1 
where @anInputValue is null 
   or blah = @anInputValue
```

You can use a different value to indicate getting all values like for instance

```
where @anInputValue = -1
   or blah = @anInputValue
```